# mv command renaming the file not moving it to the specified folder

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line, wsl-2

I have been trying to move a file from one folder to another in WSL using commmand line MV command. But instead of moving the file, it is everytime just renaming the file. And even after renaming the file is not present in the current folder as if it is removed

Suppose there is a folder TEST1 and inside that another folder TEST2
Now i try to move a file in TEST1 say, text.txt, using the command " sudo mv -v text.txt /TEST2 "
The output comes out to be " test.txt successfully renmamed to /TEST2 " and also is nowhere to be seen in TEST1.
Please help me rectify.

Comment: You seem to be unaware of the difference between `TEST2` and `/TEST2`.

Comment: @Armali: you mean `TEST1/TEST2` and `/TEST2`? :-)

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows graphical concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Armali could you please explain?

Comment: `TEST2` is a relative path (starting) in the current directory, `/TEST2` is an absolute path starting in the root directory, hence you'll find the moved file with the new name in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between moving :
1 - to the same directory (i.e. renaming inplace)
2 - to a subdirectory
3 - to a subdirectory and renaming
4 - to the root directory and renaming

```bash
mv -v text.txt TEST2.txt # 1
mv -v text.txt ./test2 # 2 (the ./ indicates current location, so test2 must be an existing subdirectory)
mv -v text.txt ./test2/TEST2.txt# 3 (test2 must also exist)
mv -v text.txt /TEST2.txt # 4 (on linux, '/' is usually called the root directory, just like 'C:/' in windows)
```

Comment: Note the leading `./` in `mv -v text.txt ./test2` is not required, and can also be used or omitted on the filename; `mv -v ./text.txt ./test2` will work, as would `mv -v text.txt test2` and `mv -v test.txt test2/` — This last one is noteworthy... if the directory `test2` does **not** exist then `mv -v text.txt test2` will rename the file text.txt to "test2", but `mv -v text.txt test2/` will give an error telling you that test2 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
sudo mv -v text.txt /TEST2
```

And this "TEST2" directory doesn't exist in the *root*, `mv` will assume you want to move it to the *root*-directory and rename 'test.txt' into 'TEST2'.

Your question is not really clear what you are actually doing or want. You say "*folder TEST1 exists and the folder TEST2 is in it*". But then why do you move 'test.txt' to /TEST2 in the *root*-directory? Where is 'TEST1'? Is that in the *root*-directory?

If you enter:

```
sudo mkdir -v /TEST2
sudo mv -v test.txt /TEST2/
```

You will actually find `/TEST2/test.txt` to exist (assuming the file 'test.txt' was in your current path). But is this what you wanted?